# What forum/bulletin software does Vimeo.com use?

Tags: web-applications, forum, vbulletin

What forum/bulletin software does [**Vimeo.com use**](http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:5585)?

Answer (score 1):

Search the forum for its own origin; its custom; http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:16873

> Is the vimeo forum software based on an existing (or even open) forum
>   platform/software (ie BBPress, Vanilla, YABB)? If so which one?
>
> *Nope we wrote it from scratch.*